# Cannot resolve symbol ViewModelProviders

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I am working on Android ViewModel architecture component but I am getting the above mentioned error when trying to initialize a ViewModel in an AppCompatActivity.

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CounterViewModel.class);
```

There are a few questions and articles related to this, and they pointed towards adding the `lifecycle:extensions` and `lifecycle:viewmodel` dependencies in the app gradle file, but I am still getting the error.

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

The package android.arch.lifecycle does not contain the class `ViewModelProviders` and it only has `ViewModelProvider` class.

What else needs to be added to access the `ViewModelProviders` class?

Edit :

Dependencies in app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':lifecycle')
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
}
```

[image]

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders. at the top right mentions adding extensions dependency should work. So it should work in your case

Comment: @Raghunandan Like I have mentioned I have added the dependencies already, it is still not showing up in the lifecycle package. Thanks

Comment: and of course you have `import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;` in your imports

Comment: @pskink No it is not there even after adding the dependencies.

Comment: you dont have `import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;` in your code?

Comment: I do have it in my code which is where it was throwing the error, I have added it in the question as well now. Thank you.

Comment: - For both ViewModel and LiveData there is a new version 2.0.0
you can add it to your app build.gradle file using this line:<br/>
`implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'` - also you can watch the available versions of any google lib here:<br/> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html<br/> you can expand any lib. for versions and sub-modules

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1` definitely has `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders`. You can see it in Android Studio, if you open the "External Libraries" portion of the project tree and examine the library contents:

[image: android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1 Contents]

Some possible reasons for not finding the `import` include:

- You have `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"` in the wrong place (it should be in the `dependencies` closure of the module's `build.gradle` file, such as `app/build.gradle`)
- You did not sync Android Studio with the Gradle build files (you are normally prompted to do this, but you can do it manually from File > Sync Project with Gradle Files from the Android Studio main menu)

Comment: Yes, the file is present under the external libraries. And I have followed the two instructions, but ViewModelProviders is still not showing up. Thank you.

Comment: @ashwinmahajan: Perhaps you have a typo. Go into "External Libraries" and fold open the `android.arch.lifecycle:extensions` line as I have in the screenshot. Right-click over the `ViewModelProviders` entry and choose "Copy Reference" from the context menu. In your list of imports, add an `import ` starting point, then paste in the `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders` that you should get from the "Copy Reference" menu item. Add a `;` at the end, and you should wind up with a valid `import` statement for this class. If that gives you an error, add a screenshot of it to your question.

Comment: You can refer to the screenshot I have added.

Comment: @ashwinmahajan: You have three modules (at least) in this project. Are you sure that this class is from the module that has the `extensions` dependency? For example, this activity is in the `:lifecycle` module, perhaps you do not have the `extensions` dependency in the `build.gradle` for `:lifecycle`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I had it under different module. Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need both `lifecycle:extensions` and `lifecycle:viewmodel` in your build.gradle file, remove

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
```

and it should be fine now. Also, you may want to migrate to AndroidX and use the 2.0.0 versions of the library.

Answer (score 2):

`ViewModelProviders` is now deprecated. Use `ViewModelProvider` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring in libary, you can modify the `implementation` to `api`